# Writing to network shared volume: WinAPI much faster than C++ fstream

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ofstream

I have a cross-platform tool, implemented in C++, that writes large binary files to an output directory. I use Boost and C++11 throughout the code. This question concerns behavior on Windows only.

When writing to a local disk, the C++ `fstream.write` API performs as well as the WinAPI `WriteFile` function. When writing to a shared volume over a local network, however, the `fstream` API performs much slower than WinAPI, anywhere from 3-13x slower.

Am I crazy?

Here are the API calls I make (in a loop, writing 4 MB chunks of dummy data). I'm writing sequentially, so seeking isn't necessary, but I listed it for completeness:

C++ fstream:

```
std::ofstream output(path, std::ios::binary | std::iostream::trunc);
output.seekp(offset);
output.write(data, size);
```

WinAPI:

```
Handle handle = CreateFileW(path,
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
SetFilePointer(handle, offset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(handle, data, size, &nwritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(handle);
```

I'm intentionally not setting any "special" flags on the Windows Handle (e.g. sequential scan, random access, no buffering, etc.).

Should I expect such a large performance improvement switching to WinAPI on Windows if I expect users to use a NAS or other network volume? Obviously I'd prefer to use the C++ standard library, but it's far too slow in this case.

---

Adding more detail:

My compiler is MSVC 2015 32-bit.

Dummy data preparation:

```
const int nsegments = 256;
const unsigned long segmentSizeMb = 4;
const unsigned long segmentSize = segmentSizeMb * 1024 * 1024;
std::vector<char> data(segmentSize);
for (long i = 0; i < segmentSize; i++) {
    data[i] = static_cast<char>(i);
}
```

Write loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nsegments; i++) {
    // Call one of the following:
    ofstream.write(data.data(), segmentSize);
    // or    
    fwrite(data.data(), 1, segmentSize, fileptr);
    // or
    DWORD nwritten;
    WriteFile(handle, data.data(), segmentSize, &nwritten, NULL);
}
```

I am measuring the write throughput using `std::chrono`, e.g.

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
int nwrites = 0;
int nwritesPerReport = 8;
...
// (inside write loop):
if (++nwrites % nwritesPerReport == 0) {
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = now - start;
    double rate = nwrites * segmentSizeMb / duration.count();
    // print rate, which has units MB/s
}
```

When writing to a local SSD, I observe the following write rates:

- fstream: 600 MB/s
- fwrite: 3200 MB/s
- WinAPI: 3200 MB/s

When writing to a HDD shared on my local network (WiFi, Windows PC):

- fstream: 1.1 MB/s
- fwrite: 14 MB/s
- WinAPI: 14 MB/s

I assume the wild rates observed when writing locally relate to differences in how each approach internally handles buffering.

The rates observed writing over the network I'm less sure about.

I've tried both disabling buffering in the fstream, and providing my own buffer, neither of which made a positive impact:

```
ofstream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(NULL, 0);
// or
std::vector<char> buf(size);
ofstream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf.data(), size);
// where size ranges from 8KB to 1 MB
```

---

I also ran the same test from two Linux VMs on different machines on the same local network:

Ubuntu 17.10 GCC 7.2.0 (Ethernet):

- fstream: 60 MB/s
- fwrite: 60 MB/s

CentOS 7 GCC 4.8.5 (WiFi):

- fstream: 20 MB/s
- fwrite: 20 MB/s

Comment: My guess is that the filesystem driver is performing synchronous writes, waiting for confirmation that the data has been received, but WinAPI doesn't.

Comment: Given how much more the c++ library does buffering wise and more this does not surprise me at all.

Comment: In WinAPI example you never sync with file system, while `ofstream` will sync it at least on exit (or potentially on each `write`?).

Comment: @VTT - *In WinAPI example you never sync with file system* really ?

Comment: @Barmar - the filesystem driver is performing asynchronous writes. *but WinAPI doesn't* - are winapi not simply call driver ??

Comment: `SetFilePointer` absolute useless call and only slow operation. use explicit offset in `WriteFile` instead - this will be more faster. also if you write data always to the end of file - you can use `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access - with this all writes will be automatically at the end

Comment: @Barmar `fstream` calls the WinAPI and WinAPI calls the file system driver. Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tested this over my home LAN between Win10 and Win7, there were no significant difference in speed. I don't know what settings you have but there is a good chance your test is wrong. Check `handle` and check `nwritten` with `size`

Comment: @RbMm I think you're understanding the problem backwards. The `WinAPI` stuff is fast, it doesn't need fixing, his problem is with the `ofstream`.

Comment: @EJP I was thinking that `fstream` calls a generic driver (e.g. `open()` on POSIX), which uses `WinAPI` for certain types of devices. And the options it uses with WinAPI are making it slow.

Comment: @Barmar - of course c++ api call `WriteFile` or `ZwWriteFile` - no other way from user mode in windows. in kernel side io subsystem already called appropriate driver . no any "generic" driver in windows. `output.write` is shell over `WriteFile`.

Comment: I've added much more detail to clarify some of the discussion here in the comments. I've removed the unnecessary seek/SetFilePointer calls to further simplify the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You have shown bits and pieces. Please make full MCVE with `int main(){...}` to demonstrate this test. You are running the program in release mode with optimization enabled? By the way, I didn't use any boost headers in my test. I am also using VS2015, 32bit, from SSD writing to HDD